# Взаимодействие с БД в Python

Tags: python

Имеет ли Python свои библиотеки для работы с СУБД (как PHP)?

Comment: Для большинства СУБД/операционных систем -- да. Если нет, то есть средства вызова функций на C и там можно использовать предлагаемый разработчиками СУБД API.

Answer (score 2):

Да, безусловно, причем для очень многих СУБД.
Однако, работать с СУБД напрямую - грустно и (идеологически) неправильно. Гораздо удобнее использовать ORM (object-relation mapping), в Python наиболее распространен [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) и надстройка над
ним - [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de)

Comment: >(идеологически) неправильно

Что у вас за идеология?

Comment: Идеология - создание переносимого, поддерживаемого кода.

Comment: Переносимого -- это portable или tolerable?

Comment: :-))) 
Ну, в каком-то смысле, оба :-)

Comment: Вы забываете о том, что ORM годится только в простых случаях. Для сложных приложений они малопригодны, так как трудно или даже невозможно выразить сложный запрос в терминах и средствах ORM.

Comment: Во-первых, таких случаев, на самом деле, при грамотно спроектированной модели данных, 80%. Остальные 20% - да, действительно требуют применения какой-то специфики используемой СУБД. Но тогда это решается, скорее, средствами СУБД - например, view/stored proc/etc.. При этом можно вполне можно определить объект, получающийся в результате этого запроса, и вызывать эту stored proc через имеющиеся в ORM средства. Получается весьма гибкий гибрид, годный в 99% случаев.

Answer (score 2):

К основным БД у Python есть либы и причем не по одной.

В своей работе использую sqlite, Firebird и Postgresql.
К примеру, кусок кода для Postgresql :

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import pg
pgcon=None

def opendb(host,base,user,password):
    global pgcon
    pgcon=pg.connect(dbname=base,host=host,user=user,passwd=password)

def closedb():
    global pgcon
    pgcon.close()

def querysql(val):
    global pgcon
    pgcon.query(val)
    pass

def queryparam(sql_val,param):
    global pgcon
    pgcon.query(sql_val % pg.escape_bytea(param))

def queryresparam(val):
    global pgcon    
    f=pg.unescape_bytea(pgcon.query(val).getresult()[0][0])
    return f

def querysqlres(val):
    global pgcon
data=pgcon.query(val).getresult()
return data
```

Comment: Как и в случае с MySQL, это сильно платформо-зависимый код. Я еще раз порекомендовал бы посмотреть в сторону ORM, которые, по-первых, делают код максималоьно переносимым между различными СУБД, и во вторых - упрощают работу с БД, делая ее в частности объектно-ориентированной.

Comment: самое забавное что не сильно. потому что работа с базами в python сделана однообразно. Использование ORM в большинстве случаев не оправдано. Потому что нельзя использовать "вкусности" базы, а использовать к примеру тот же Oracle всего лишь в качестве хранилища данных, это несколько расточительно.

Comment: @cavinc, не забывайте про экранирование и прочие нюансы составления запросов. SQL-инъекции актуальны до сих пор, а уж сколько багов вылезает!

И еще раз подчеркну, что и через ORM можно прекрасно использовать специфику низлежащей СУБД. Отмечу, что у лично мы (наша компания) использует *и* ORM, *и* специфику СУБД.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно доставлять mysql-python (кажется так называется), а вообще поиск в [гугле](http://www.google.by/search?hl=ru&client=opera&hs=KaN&rls=ru&channel=suggest&q=python+db+connect&oq=python+db+connect&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2772l4167l0l10l9l0l5l5l0l238l390l0.1.1l2) даёт неплохой результат)

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой примерчик, думаю разберётесь

```
import _mysql
db=_mysql.connect("localhost","user", "pass", "base")
db.query(r"SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE field1 < 5")
r=db.store_result()
print(r.fetch_row())
```

Answer (score 1):

На все популярные базы данных в python сообществе есть свои пакеты.

MySql-Python для Mysql
psycopg2 для Postgresql
sqlite3 для Sqlite3
и тд.
Это по своей сути пакеты с низкоуровневыми расширениям на С для взаимодействия с базой данных.

Любая ORM это как правило надстройка над низкоуровневыми расширениями на С (как в Sqlalchemy) или над пакетами с низкоуровневыми расширениям на С (как в orm в фреймворке django).

А использовать всегда и везде ORM это **ЗЛО**. Использование ORM должно быть продиктовано задачей, а не наоборот.

Comment: Подозревая, что Автор вопроса хочет работать с СУБД для хранения там данных, я и рекомендую там использовать ORM. Тем более, обычно ORM позволяет выполнять произвольные (читай, платформо-зависимые, и в частности maintanance) SQL-запросы (например, я в SQLAlchemy этой возможностью иногда пользуюсь)

Добавлю, 99% задач с СУБД связаны с хранением там данных, которые вне СУБД отлично ложатся на некую объектную модель. Поэтому ORM надо использовать в 99% случаев.

И вот тот самый 1% только подтверждает это правило :-)

Comment: ORM накладывает ряд ограничений. Это использование триггеров, сложных каскадных запросов, временных таблиц, процедур, гор. и верт. шардинга и прочих порой необходимых тонкостей которые есть только в одной из баз и ORM ограничивает их использование. Кроме того ORM кушает процессорное время на свой код. Именно поэтому от использования ORM отказываются в простых программах и высоконагруженных системах.
Я отнюдь не противник ORM, а скорее сторонник, но всё же считаю что 99% это очень большой процент. Имхо, для 60%-70% случаев годиться ORM и 30-40% случаев использования ORM будет излишним.

Comment: Но ведь ORM *не запрещает* их использование! Наоборот, делая platfrom-specific запросы через ORM, можно получить на выходе не raw rowset, а вполне себе object list. 

P.S. Кстати - как-то смотрел различными средствами на загрузку одного реального сервера. Так вот ORM там вообще менее 1% давал. Весьма много поедал шаблонизатор, но активнее всего - самые, казалось бы, обычные запросы к БД. Схема была сделана по всем канонам, улучшать было практически некуда.