# Как в Django REST записать данные в базу данных PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, angularjs, django-rest-framework

Сейчас у меня есть набор значений полей формы, они передаются в API. 
Как организовать подключение к БД, выполнение запроса и возврат результата выполнения запроса в виде `Response`-ответа обратно в AngularJS? 
Для основных методов работы с БД нашел [такой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/20059/181728)
Однако не совсем понимаю, куда их лучше добавлять?

База не та, что используется для самого `Django`.

У меня есть `API`:

```
class SomeAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         data = request.data 
         # здесь на основе data должен формироваться запрос, подключение к БД, выполнение запроса и возврат ответа (успешно/неуспешно выполнился запрос, например)
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

В `settings.py` модуль `psycopg2` подключен, используется для БД `Django`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполнение простейшего запроса:

```
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extensions, logging

...

params = {
    'dbname': 'db_name',
    'user': 'test',
    'password': 'test',
    'host': '192.168.1.1',
    'port': '5432'
}
pgcon=psycopg2.connect(**params)
query = 'SELECT NOW() AS answer;'
cur = pgcon.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extensions.cursor)
cur.execute(query)
point = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(point);
pgcon.close()
```